# Exim4 only sending to certain email addresses

Tags: email, exim

I've recently set up a development server at my job to test out certain features. I am setting up exim4 to be the MTA for the server. However, when I test and send emails to my account on the server, even though I have multiple entries in `/etc/aliases` it only sends to one of the email addresses.

The entry is my `/etc/aliases` file is:

`joshua: **@gmail.com, **@apps.gmail.com`

Below is the output of `tail /var/log/exim4/mainlog`. I've changed the email addresses, but the rest of the data is the same. `**@gmail.com` is my regular gmail account, `**@apps.gmail.com` is a Google apps account for my job, and `account@this.server` is the server's domain name.

```
2013-02-04 02:39:55 1U2Geh-0000aO-LZ DKIM: d=gmail.com s=20120113 c=relaxed/relaxed a=rsa-sha256 [verification succeeded]
2013-02-04 02:39:55 1U2Geh-0000aO-LZ <= **@gmail.com H=mail-wi0-f179.google.com [209.85.212.179] P=esmtp S=1757 id=CAM+SEUAx2UK8cDKe-MO22maib0at4kO=J+tQniEy=rxmPpbgjg@mail.gmail.com
2013-02-04 02:39:56 1U2Geh-0000aO-LZ => **@apps.gmail.com <account@this.server> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=aspmx.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:4002:c04::1b] X=TLS1.2:RSA_ARCFOUR_SHA1:128 DN="C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=mx.google.com"
2013-02-04 02:39:56 1U2Geh-0000aO-LZ => **@gmail.com <account@this.server> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2607:f8b0:4002:c02::1b] X=TLS1.2:RSA_ARCFOUR_SHA1:128 DN="C=US,ST=California,L=Mountain View,O=Google Inc,CN=mx.google.com"
2013-02-04 02:39:56 1U2Geh-0000aO-LZ Completed
```

When I send a test email, it sends to my apps email address but not my gmail address.

I thought it might be an issue with `exim4` not sending to multiple email addresses, so I changed the `/etc/aliases` file to only reflect my `**@gmail.com` email address but it also failed to send even though there were no specific errors in the `mainlog`.

I also tested to see if I could send emails directly to my gmail account. I ran the command

`echo "Test" | mail -s "Subject" "**@gmail.com"`

and it succeeded.

Basically, when I send an email to `joshua@this.server` it successfully sends an email to `**@apps.gmail.com` but not `**@gmail.com`. However, when I send an email directly to `**@gmail.com` it goes through. Any ideas?

UPDATE: The emails do not show up at all in Gmail, including in the spam folder.

Comment: Check your spam folder.

Comment: Edited to reflect this. The emails don't show up in my spam folder.